# Android Studio Эмулятор

Tags: android, android-studio

Пытаюсь запустить приложение на эмуляторе Android Studio. Фреймворк  на котором основано приложение имеет требования к архитектуре процессора
Snapdragon меньше 850 такие как 650, 710
и поддержку Open CL
Как пример, это Самсунг S9 или HTC U12.
Как мне это эмулировать? Т.е. x84 и x84_64 образы систем не подходят.
Образ arm64-v8a вроде должен подходить, но он грузится по полчаса, всё в нём тормозит, установки приложения я так и не дождался. 
Можно ли каким-то образом съэмулировать? Или только покупать устройство?

Comment: Эмулятор Genymotion не пробовали? Он быстрее стандартного эмулятора Android Studio

Comment: Либо воспользуйтесь эмулятором от Microsoft https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/ru/vs/msft-android-emulator/

Comment: @danilshik Genymotion пробовал, мне показалось та же скорость. О эмуляторе от Microsoft не знал, устанавливаю, спасибо

Comment: Толку не будет, MSemu не сильно быстрее, работать одновременно с этими эмуляторами на практике не возможно, нервы на тормоза и ожидание заканчиваются раньше :) правильный вариант только один, устройство + ADB.

Comment: @NewView да, я уже понял. Сейчас установил эмулятор от Microsoft. Там, к сожалению, нет таких систем и API максимально 23. Не знаю может можно установить другие конфигурации с VisualStudio, но автономно только эти. Видимо нужно покупать телефон, а то одни тормоза.